# Magento 2: Image resize changes the orientation of image

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I am facing problem with the resize,Image orientation get changed on resize (rotated left to right).

Original Image size: 2320px × 3088px,

Resize: 279px x 349px

Resize code:

```
        $imageFactory = $this->_imageFactory->create();
        $imageFactory->open($absolutePath);
        $imageFactory->quality(100);
        $imageFactory->constrainOnly('true');
        $imageFactory->keepAspectRatio('true');
        $imageFactory->keepFrame('true');
        $imageFactory->keepTransparency('true');
        $imageFactory->backgroundColor([255, 255, 255]);
        $imageFactory->resize($width, $height);
        $imageFactory->save($imageResized);
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will help someone, I have created a function which will change the orientation of image and save in the same directory.

```
$absolutePath = $this->_mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath() . $image;
$this->__image_orientate($absolutePath);

public function __image_orientate($source, $quality = 90, $destination = null)

{

    if ($destination === null) {
        $destination = $source;
        
    }
    
        $info = getimagesize($source);
    
        if ($info['mime'] === 'image/jpeg') {
            $exif = exif_read_data($source);
            if (!empty($exif['Orientation']) && in_array($exif['Orientation'], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])) {
                $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
                if (in_array($exif['Orientation'], [3, 4])) {
                    $image = imagerotate($image, 180, 0);
                }
                if (in_array($exif['Orientation'], [5, 6])) {
                    $image = imagerotate($image, -90, 0);
                }
                if (in_array($exif['Orientation'], [7, 8])) {
                    $image = imagerotate($image, 90, 0);
                }
                if (in_array($exif['Orientation'], [2, 5, 7, 4])) {
                    imageflip($image, IMG_FLIP_HORIZONTAL);
                }
                imagejpeg($image, $destination, $quality);
            }
        }
     return true;
 
}
```